# ABRecordCopyValue only returning Facebook email for Contact and ignoring others

Tags: ios, abrecord, abperson

I am trying to compare the emails of a selected phone contact to the emails of registered users in my app to see if they are registered.

It should be simple enough. Get the recordRef, copy the email multiValue, then compare:

```
-(void) checkForUser:(ABRecordRef) person {

    ABMultiValueRef contactEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    NSLog(@"emails are %@", contactEmails); // seeing error in log

    ...
    // check the emails against registered users.
```

This works great most of the time. Problem comes with unified contacts. My contact for example is a unified record with my Facebook, home, work emails all in one contact. When I run `checkUser:` with that `ABRecordRef` it is ONLY showing my Facebook email even though there are 4 others.

I am thinking this is a bug. Am I missing something about unified cards?

Comment: On an iPad no code handy. Do more searching on SO - normally you ask for an array of all emails - I recently saw such a post where the user was trying to get home not work address.

Comment: I do get the array of emails from the `multiValueRef` afterward. In the `NSlog` here though I can already see which emails are being retrieved and for the unified/facebook (whatever the problem is) it is not getting all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, you can see if your code is similar - if so no more info to provide you:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
//CFShow(multiValue);
if(multiValue) {
    for(CFIndex j=0; j<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue); ++j) {
        //CFShow(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, j) );
        CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, j);
        if(![emailKey isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)label]) {
            CFRelease(label);
            continue;
        }
        CFRelease(label);

        CFStringRef string = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, j);
        NSString *finalStr = CFBridgingRelease(string);

        NSArray *array = [finalStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
        if([array count] == 3)  finalStr = (NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:1];

        [data replaceObjectAtIndex:emailAddress withObject:finalStr];
        break;
    }
    CFRelease(multiValue);
}
```

Comment: Yup, I'm essentially doing the same thing. Pretty sure it's a bug with the unified contact somehow. As if it is just grabbing the first of the unified contacts and taking that email. I'm not sure how the unification process works so it is hard to say. Thanks though.

Comment: Add a bug to bugreporter.apple.com - mine usually get fixed at some point.